# polymer_elements equivalent of paper-elements <core-collapse> element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-elements

Does anyone knows if there is an equivalent of paper-element core-collapse in any of the polymer-elements catalogue found at https://elements.polymer-project.org/? I cannot seem to find an equivalent. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-collapse ? 
Looks the same as core-collapse.

Comment: I don't see the declaration for the title of the collapse in the example. Or is it some other element that is used to trigger the collapse?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-collapse/blob/master/demo/index.html#L57 (at the end of the line)